# Configure global Json.NET converter based on type

Tags: c#, json.net

I would like the following global Json.NET configuration:

- If the Enum type is `Foo`, use the default serialization logic for enums (output integer value, e.g. `3`).
- Otherwise, use the `StringEnumConverter` (output string value, e.g. `"Red"`)

I want to use a global configuration since Web API's ApiController automatically converts responses to JSON.

```
// Global Json.NET configuration in Global.asax.cs   
HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

// Serialize enum values as description instead of integers in JSON.
// I wish to conditionally apply this converter.
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new
StringEnumConverter());
```

Current result:

- Always uses the `StringEnumConverter`.

What is the recommended solution here?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a custom `JsonConverter` derived from Json.Net's `StringEnumConverter`.  In the `WriteJson` method, check whether the value is a `Foo` enum, and if so, write it as an integer.  Otherwise, use the base class `WriteJson` method to write the value.  (You do not need to override `ReadJson` because the `StringEnumConverter` already handles reading both the string and numeric values.)

```
class StringEnumExceptFooConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is Foo || value is Foo?)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value);
        }
        else
        {
            base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your configuration, replace the `StringEnumConverter` with your custom converter.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
    new StringEnumExceptFooConverter());
```

Demo fiddle (console app): https://dotnetfiddle.net/3iUIKT